# add_five = lambda y: add_numbers(5,y) and add_five = lambda y: 5+y

Tags: python

I read such a script:

```
add_numbers = lambda x, y: x+y
add_five = lambda y: add_numbers(5,y)
```

It derive a new function of one variable, `add_five`, that adds 5 to its argument:

from this point, introduced `functools`

```
In [9]: from functools import partial
In [10]: add_five = partial(add_numbers, 5)
In [11]: add_five(7)
Out[11]: 12
```

As a novice, I guess it can be easily achieved by

```
add_five = lambda y: 5+y
add_six = lambda y: 6+y
```

I am confused what's the benefit if not define `add_five` in a straighforward method?

Comment: Lambda functions are useful when you need small, *anonymous*, single expression functions.  Lots of python methods take functions as arguments, and lambdas are convenient for this.

Comment: Why a lambda at all? `def add_five(y): return y+5`

Comment: @chrisz I think `lambda` is a distraction here. It is simply bad style in this case (indeed, assigning the result of a lambda expression to a name is explicitly against PEP8). However, the overall concept here is that of higher-order functions. Which are very useful.

Comment: As to the benefit, these are meant to be examples showing you a technique of a function that returns another function. Of course, these are just simple examples. But what if you needed a function, `add_something`, but you didn't know what `something` is going to be until run-time?

Comment: The idea here is the concept of code reutilization and currying (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). The script shows a *general* function that adds any two numbers together (i.e. `add_numbers`) and shows how a *particular* function can use its logic to perform a *particular operation*. The issue is that the logic is *too small* and you can't actually see the benefits of the pattern. But imagine if `add_numbers` had a complex logic with many lines of code, and `add_five` had the same complex logic, only with the difference that the argument `x` is always `5`.Why copy/paste the whole code?

Comment: @RafaelC I would say this isn't an example of currying per se, it is [partial application instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application), and the use of higher order functions more generally.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is kind of a polemic discussion.Sometimes partial application is referred to as a type of currying, and sometimes as a different concept :) Tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utility of `partial` is to **easily create specialised versions of functions** from a general definition.

The case of  adding numbers  can be illustrating here `add_numbers` is the general case.

```
from functools import partial


def add_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y

add5 = partial(add_nums, 5)
```

Here `add5` is a specialised case of `add_numbers` roughly equivalent to

```
def add5(x):
    return add_numbers(x, 5)
```

Adding numbers is a very trivial example and does not show the utility of `partial`

The following is a **simple example that may better show the utility of partial.**
Consider writing a procedure to compute the square root of a number using [the Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).

```
def square_root(x, tolerance, convergence_test):
    y = 1
    while not convergence_test(x, y, tolerance):
        y = (y + x/y)/2
    return y
```

For most numbers, the convergence test can simply check the difference between `y` squared and `x` is `0`. Let's call this the absolute error of the estimate

```
def absolute_error(x, y, tolerance):
    return abs(x - y**2) <= tolerance
```

For very large and small numbers, using absolute error of the estimate can lead to wrong answers for various reasons. In those cases, it is better to use the relative error:

```
def relative_error(x, y, tolerance):
    return abs(x/(y**2) - 1) <= tolerance
```

With `partial`, we can easily create specialised functions for using the either absolute and relative error.

```
sqrt_rel_err = partial(square_root, convergence_test=relative_error)
sqrt_abs_err = partial(square_root, convergence_test=absolute_error)
```

Now using either is trivial

```
>>> sqrt_rel_err(2, 0.00001)
1.4142156862745097
>>> sqrt_abs_err(2, 0.00001)
1.4142156862745097
```

And for small numbers: we see using **absolute error** gives the wrong answer (especially when the tolerance is greater than the number we are trying to get the square root of)

```
>>> x = sqrt_abs_err(1e-6, 0.00001)
>>> x**2
4.4981362843183905e-06
```

Whilst the **relative error** method yields a more accurate answer.

```
>>> x = sqrt_rel_err(1e-6, 0.00001)
>>> x**2
1.0000003066033492e-06
```